# Find DB Restore History along with machine hostname/ip address

Tags: sql-server

I want to find out from which laptop or desktop a given database was restored during a given time period. Currently every one in my team is using the same SQL Server user id, so I have to find from which machine the database restore was triggered.

That way I can figure out who actually did the database restore.

I have already found the below query which gives the details of restore history. But this doesn't give the ipaddress or hostname of the machine from which restore was done.

```
 SELECT 
   [rs].[destination_database_name], 
   [rs].[restore_date], 
   [bs].[backup_start_date], 
   [bs].[backup_finish_date], 
   [bs].[database_name] as [source_database_name], 
   [bmf].[physical_device_name] as [backup_file_used_for_restore]
FROM msdb..restorehistory rs
INNER JOIN msdb..backupset bs ON [rs].[backup_set_id] = [bs]. 
[backup_set_id]
INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily bmf ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf]. 
[media_set_id] 
ORDER BY [rs].[restore_date] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the restore datetime from the query you put, you can go to Application event viewer and check the computer name
 Example: [image]

Comment: Is that the client hostname or the server hostname? I suspect the latter and I think the OP is asking for the former.